# fix the code it comes up saying error expected expression before 'else'

Tags: c

There is an error with the else statement and that something should be coming before it. 
I cant really figure out whats wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int random1_6()
{
    return ((rand() % 6) + 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, d, equal, sum;
    srand(time(NULL));
    a = random1_6();
    b=random1_6();
    sum = a + b;
    printf("\n The player rolled: %d + %d = %d. \n the players point is %d. \n", a, b, sum, sum);
    if (sum ==7);
    {
        printf("The player wins. \n");
    }
    else (sum !=7); 
    {
        c = random1_6();
        d=random1_6();
        equal = c + d;     
        printf("\n The player rolled: %d + %d = %d", c, d, equal);
}
```

Comment: remove `(sum !=7)` in your else statement.

Comment: You have also to remove the comma (;) after if(sum ==7)

Answer (score 0):

(1) You don't have to put `;` after an `if`. If you write:

```
if(condition); { block; }
```

C interprets it as: Check `condition`, and whatever is the result always execute `block`.

(2+3) The `else` condition is wrong and meaningless: if you reach the `else` then `sum != 7` is always true, so there's no need to check for it.

In any case, if you need it, the correct syntax is:

```
}
else if(sum != 7) 
{
```

With the `if` and without the `;`

(4) You also forgot to return something from `main` function, declared as returning an `int` value.

(5) in your code the final `}` was missing, maybe just a wrong copy&paste?

Here is your code with the above corrections:

```
int random1_6()
{
    // enter code here
    return ((rand() % 6) + 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a, b, c, d, equal, sum;

    srand(time(NULL));

    a = random1_6();
    b = random1_6();

    sum = a + b;

    printf("\n The player rolled: %d + %d = %d. \n the players point is %d. \n", a, b, sum, sum);

    if(sum == 7) // (1) Remove ";", it's wrong!
    {
       printf("The player wins. \n");
    } 
    else // (2) Remove "(sum !=7)", it's useless. (3) Remove ";" , it's wrong!
    // else if(sum != 7) // This is the correct sintax for an else if, just in case :-)
    {
        c = random1_6();
        d = random1_6();
        equal = c + d;     
        printf("\n The player rolled: %d + %d = %d", c, d, equal);
    }

    return 0; // (4) The function is declared returning an int, so you must return something.
} // (5) This bracket was missing :-)
```

Hope everything is clear

Answer (score -2):

Your else statement is wrong.
here is the if else syn text.

```
if (some-condition) {
} else{
}
```

Or you can use

```
if (some-condition) {
} else if (some-condition) {
}
```

Just remove (sum !=7) your code will work.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the unnecessary semicolon.

```
if (sum == 7) {
 printf("The player wins. \n");
} else {
 c = random1_6();
 d = random1_6();
 equal = c + d; 
 printf("\n The player rolled: %d + %d = %d", c, d, equal);
}
```